# Extract REGEXP Substring SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I want to extract a specific number value from this query...

Column: name
Four rows for this example:

- 1/2 Product1 some_description 1200 GR more data... (UND)
- 1/4 Product2 some_description 2400G more data (KG more data)
- Product3 some_description 2200 GRS more data...
- 1/4 Product4 some_description 1800GR more data UND...

I want the integer value only. I want with the query:

- 1200
- 2400
- 2200
- 1800

The patterns are:

- [0-9]{4} G
- [0-9]{4}GR
- [0-9]{4} GRS

How can i use this regexp on a SQL Query to parse an attribute value?

`SELECT FROM myTable 
SUBSTRING(name, (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [name])),4) as peso`

This extract some values, but not in correct order... I think that i can apply LEFT with length until integer value, but i don't know how resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(
INT, 
(REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING(
        nome,
        (
            PATINDEX(
                '%[0-9]%',
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        nome,
                        '1/2',
                        ''
                    ),
                    '1/4',
                    ''
                )
            )
        ),
        4
    ),
    'G',
    ''
))) as pesoTotal
```

This resolve the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  In SQL Server, the simplest method for your data is:

```
select left(name, 4) as peso
from mytable t;
```

That is, the first four characters seem to be what you want.

If the first four characters may not all be digits, then you want to use `patindex()`:

```
select left(name, patindex('%[^0-9]%', name + ' ') - 1) as peso
from myTable t;
```

Comment: This is a field, Product1 some_description 1200 GR more description...
I only want the integer value. Your query gets first number... I modify it, but with another rows, doesn't match with integer value.

Comment: @dankkomcg . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked.  And in this question, you clearly want the first four digits.  If you have *another* question, then ask it as *another* question.  If you change this question, then you might invalidate this answer and that could draw downvotes.

Comment: Its the same, i edit it because its possible that users don't understand. No First four digits, only the First Integer, if you want, formed for four digits. But its the same question.

Comment: @dankkomcg . . . This answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like `SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][G ][GR]%', name),4)`, if they always do use the same pattern.  Will get some false positives ('1400 Rhinos', '3216GGG' and the like).