# SQL Server extract integers from string using regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, matching

I have a string (unc file path) that I need to extract some integers that will be embedded in the string in a semi-predictable way.

Example strings:

```
\\servername\folder1\FTP\folder2\512/862450_FileBundle.zip
--OR-- : \\servername\folder1\FTP\folder2\512\862450_FileBundle.zip
--OR-- : servername/folder1/FTP/folder2/512/862450_FileBundle.zip
```

The following regular expression regular expression will match on any integer value that is bounded by a forward or backslash: `(\/|\\)\d+(\/|\\)`

So the REGEX above would match on "\512\", or "\512/", or "/512/" or even "/512\".

I have tried the following SQL and other variations without success:

```
DECLARE @testString varchar(50) = '\\servername\folder1\FTP\folder2\512/862450_FileBundle.zip'
SELECT PATINDEX('%(\/|\\)\d+(\/|\\)%', @testString)
```

I'm not terribly familiar with REGEX and SQL so I'm not even sure this is possible.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support full regex like you are trying to do. I am not even sure which part of the string you are trying to extract here.

Comment: The requirement is to match between slashes (forward, backward, or any combination) which is why I was looking at REGEX as a possible solution.  If a simple SQL solution is not possible, and I don't really think it is, we'll just create a c# report to display what we need.  In this example, "512" would be the string to find.

Comment: But why 512? Is it because it is the first folder that is nothing but a number? Or the last folder with nothing but a number? What do you do when there are two folders with nothing but a number?

Comment: @SeanLange - By my reading, because it's the first folder that's entirely numeric it's it name.

Comment: The folder that is integers only is of special significance to our system.  It indicates a client identifier.  So it's important to find the part of the path that is all integers and starts and end with either a forward or backward slash.  This data is contained in a 3rd party logging database that we are reporting against. @SeanLange - there would never be another folder comprised of all integers.  I admit this is a very peculiar case.

Comment: SQL Server does not support REGEX Substrings. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947027/extract-regexp-substring-sql-server on how to extract Numbers on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have as good pattern matching abilities as regular expressions.  You can search for the pattern:

```
[/\\][0-9]%[/\\]
```

That is, slash followed by a digit followed by any other string followed by a slash.  This will match any characters after the first digit, but your examples have nothing of the form `/1abc/`.

If this is sufficient, then this does the trick:

```
select v.*, 
       left(v2.str2, patindex('%[/\\]%', v2.str2) - 1)
from (values ('\\servername\folder1\FTP\folder2\512/862450_FileBundle.zip')) v(str) cross apply
     (values (stuff(v.str, 1, patindex('%[/\\][0-9]%[/\\]%', v.str), ''))) v2(str2)
```

Comment: Given the parameters of our use case, this works just fine.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Other than writing a UDF to loop through the characters, the only thing I can think of is brute force approach...

*(The User Defined Function might be your least worst option.)*

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=face1befe5e7c74f457846fc37eca649

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUBSTRING(test.unc_file_path, headMatch.pos+1, headMatch.chars)
FROM
  test
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MIN(pos), MIN(chars)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      PATINDEX('%' + head + body + tail + '%', test.unc_file_path)  AS pos, chars
    FROM
    (
                 SELECT '\'
       UNION ALL SELECT '/'
    )
      head(head)
    CROSS JOIN
    (
                 SELECT 1, '[0-9]'
       UNION ALL SELECT 2, '[0-9][0-9]'
       UNION ALL SELECT 3, '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
       UNION ALL SELECT 4, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
       UNION ALL SELECT 5, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    )
      body(chars, body)
    CROSS JOIN
    (
                 SELECT '\'
       UNION ALL SELECT '/'
    )
      tail(tail)
  )
    match
  WHERE
    pos > 0
)
  headMatch(pos, chars)
```

Comment: This is a robust solution but a bit verbose for the current need.  That said, it works brilliantly.  And, our DBA loathes user defined functions...

Comment: @phigit - Then make a table with the combinations you want to search for, and join on that. Half the SQL is just making those combinations....